# Named Query JSF using like clause

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to retrieve all name from table name column when I type any character for  auto complete in search box but I am not being able to populate name in the search box,

here is my named query section to  retrieve all items name

```
@NamedQuery(name="Item.findItembyName", query=" FROM Item e WHERE e.name like :name" )
```

and respected DAO implementation is

```
public List<Item> findItemName(String name) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println("itemDao name" +name);
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("Item.findItembyName").setParameter("name", "%"+ name +"%" );

        return query.list();
}
```

BEAN controller for calling service and DAO  layers to populate names of item in the view xhtml

```
public List<String> complete(String query){         
        List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Item> queries = depositService.findItemName(query);
              for(int i = 0 ; i < queries.size() ; i++){    
                 for (Item item : queries) {                        
                     nameList.add(item.getName());
                 }
              }         
         return nameList;
}
```

The item name from the table is not populating in the  name list array and search box in view section is not autocomplete

Comment: LIKE is used like this > where Column like '%stringHere%'. When you use % it means it can be anything, so, % at the start means ANYTHING the your string, and in the end it your string then ANYTHING. Both sides, means ANYTHING yourstring ANYTHING

Comment: Did you make sure that in your `complete` method you have a filled list?